# Rename a file in the file object on upload using Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, file

I m currently uploading a file successfully. The issue is, the file is uploaded in a file storage folder and as all the files are stored there, there is a risk that a user may upload a file with the same name. What will happen is the file will get uploaded and automatically renamed however the file which the user has uploaded will not have the filename associated with that user. e.g User 1 has uploaded fileA.docx. User 2 has uploaded fileA.docx. fileA.docx for User 2 will be renamed to fileA(1).docx  however the stored filename under User 2 will be fileA.docx. So when viewing the files, User 2 will be given fileA.docx which is for User 1.

To solve this issue, I want to rename the file when uploaded to a timestamp and then uplaod the file, and also associate the file with the user. e.g User 1 uploads fileB.docx. Upon submission, the file will be renamed to fileB2082017231.docx and then uploaded and the filename stored with the User 1 record.

Php Code (Where the upload is done)

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">Evidence Upload</label>
        <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
        <p class="help-block">Upload evidence here. Ensure filename does not have spaces</p>
</div>
```

Jquery file where the upload is carried out

```
var myFileList = document.getElementById('exampleInputFile').files;



// Grab the first File Object from the FileList
    var myFile = myFileList[0];
   if(!(myFile==null))
    {
// Set some variables containing the three attributes of the file
    var myFileName = myFile.name;
    var myFileSize = myFile.size;
    var myFileType = myFile.type;

    switch(myFileType)
    {
        case 'image/jpeg':          
        var extension = 'jpg';
            break;
        case 'image/png':
        var extension = 'png';
            break;
        case 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet':
        var extension = '.xlsx';
            break;
        case 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document':
        var extension = '.docx';
            break;
        case 'application/pdf':
        var extension = '.pdf';
    }


// Let's upload the complete file object
    uploadFile(myFile);     
    function uploadFile(myFileObject) {
// Open Our formData Object
var formData = new FormData();

// Append our file to the formData object
// Notice the first argument "file" and keep it in mind
formData.append('my_uploaded_file', myFileObject);

// Create our XMLHttpRequest Object
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Open our connection using the POST method
xhr.open("POST", '../dbfiles/upload.php');

// Send the file
xhr.send(formData);}
```

Upload.php

```
<?php


if ( 0 < $_FILES['my_uploaded_file']['error'] ) 
{
    echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['my_uploaded_file']['error'] . '<br>';
}
else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['my_uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], 
     '../uploads/' . $_FILES['my_uploaded_file']['name']);
}
move_uploaded_file(

// this is where the file is temporarily stored on the server when uploaded
// do not change this
$_FILES['my_uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],

// this is where you want to put the file and what you want to name it
// in this case we are putting in a directory called "uploads"
// and giving it the original filename
'uploads/' . $_FILES['my_uploaded_file']['name']
);

?>
```

The variables

```
var myFileName = myFile.name;
var myFileSize = myFile.size;
var myFileType = myFile.type;
```

is used to store the details in the Mysql db for associated to a particular file name. My question is, how do I rename the file in the fileobject based on my current code above.

Other issues with this code
1. When file is uploaded with spaces in the filename, only the first name before the white space is stored in the db, and thus the file is lost. Would appreciate it if a solution for this is also given.

Comment: Why not doing it on server side?
[Answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705639/how-to-rename-uploaded-file-before-saving-it-into-a-directory)
 [Answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530919/renaming-a-file-before-uploading-to-server)

Comment: The server side is for uploading the file separately and storing the name of the file separately. The xhr connection sends file without an id. So associating the files to the relevant user won't be possible.

Comment: Why it's not possible? Do you have a login system implemented or what? Even if there is no login system, you could start the session before uploading and adding a unique key to the session. Then, just before moving the file on server side, take that unique id from session, concatenate the timestamp and the file extension and save that file with new filename. I'm sure it's possible.

Comment: Thanks alot mate. I used your logic, instead of session I used timestamp however and its perfect. Please answer below so I can accept as correct answer.

Comment: I'm glad you made it. Welcome to Stack Overflow!